# Selenium unable to send keys to a combobox element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-finance

I have been trying to create an automated way of adding stocks to google finance, using selenium. I am able to login and get to the adding of the new investment, but that's where I get stuck.

Steps to reproduce:

Create a new portfolio in google finance. Populate the portfolio with at least 1 item. Next, when you run the script as below, it gets to clicking investment but is unable to send any stock names to the combo box.

Code:

```
class Google:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.url = "https://accounts.google.com"
        self.driver = uc.Chrome()
        self.driver.delete_all_cookies()
        self.time = 60
    
    def login_and_goto_google_finance(self, email, password):
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20) \
            .until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'identifier'))) \
            .send_keys(f'{email}' + Keys.ENTER)
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20) \
            .until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'Passwd'))) \
            .send_keys(f'{password}' + Keys.ENTER)
        
    def navigate_to_site(self, url, wait_enabled=True):
        if wait_enabled:
            sleep(self.time/20)
        self.driver.get(url)
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Investment"]').click()
        self.enter_symbol("BP", 1, 20240201, 100)
        sleep(60*self.time)
        
        
    def enter_symbol(self, symbol_name, qty, date, price):
        try:
            x = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'Ax4B8 ZAGvjd')]")
            print(x.aria_role)
            sleep(1)
            x.click()
            sleep(1)
            x.send_keys(f'{symbol_name}'+Keys.ENTER)
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            sleep(60*self.time)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-u", "--username", type=str, help="Email Id for logging in to Google", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--password", type=str, help="Password for logging in to Google", required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    google = Google()
    google.login_and_goto_google_finance(args.username, args.password)
    google.navigate_to_site(<link_to_your_portfolio_here>)
```

What am I doing wrong here, and what should be the correct way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locator `"//*[contains(@class, 'Ax4B8 ZAGvjd')]"` fits two elements. `find_element` returns the first element in the DOM, but you want to send the data to the second one, so you need to use a more specific locator using ancestor elements

```
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="M52nVb ytPNkd"]//input[@class="Ax4B8 ZAGvjd"]')
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly. It seems like I was looking at the wrong ancestor in my attempts at this. Thanks a ton!